# How can I resize the range selection of an active cell formula?

Tags: excel, vba

I made a macro that inserts a new row, but I have a cell with an average formula, it's: `=AVERAGE(B52:B57)`, I want to make a macro to add an extra row to the range selection formula, to have the next result: `=AVERAGE(B52:B58)`, I don´t know how to add it.

Comment: When you insert a row `within` the range i.e 52-57, the formula will automatically get updated. If you insert the row at 52th or at 58th row then the formula will not get updated. I think you are trying to insert row at 58th row.  So you can do two things. **1.** Easiest would be to insert row at 57th position **2.** OR insert row at 58th position and then readjust the formula using `rng.Formula = "=AVERAGE(B52:B" & InsertedRow & ")"`

Comment: I find defining the range to include future cells works, so B52:B60 for example . Test it and also make sure no other data is already there.

Comment: Thank you so much! The solution of Siddhartha works, I'm kind of new on VBA, I have another question, using the same format of concatenating the range as the solution, how can I use the formula "averageif"? I tried this: ="AVERAGEIF(C:48:C" & c& "& ","& "<>0")". Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So, see this:
[image]

```
=AVERAGE(B$52:B60)
```

So to cell 59 gives 45 and including cell 60 still gives 45.